# adding video overlay over youtube <object> with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, youtube

I have the page with YouTube video (object - not iframe) and need to add the image over it. All works fine in Chrome, but in IE the image is below the YouTube player. So I searched for the info and found that for IE I need to add `param wmode="opaque"` inside the youtube's `<object>`.

For some reason, I can't add that parameter right into HTML, I need to do it after the page is rendered. So I am doing this:

Example page after rendering:

```
<span class="video">
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="width:521px; height:427px;" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/sP5ntTD2ta0">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/sP5ntTD2ta0" />
</object>
</span>
```

I am adding this after document is loaded:

```
$('.video object').append('<param name="wmode" value="opaque"/>');
```

But the image in IE is still below the YouTube player.

I think that I need somehow to re-render the page, but how?  (I've already tried to use `wrap()`, `unwrap()` - no success, sorry I am "green").

Comment: You might try looking at `z-index` css property or maybe make a separate element and using styles to place it on top.

`<span class="video">...</span><div id="overlay"></div>`

Comment: Thanks, i already tried that, without success.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the HTML5 video tag.

```
<video id="video" width="521px" height="427px" controls="controls" preload="auto">   
    <source src="http://www.youtube.com/v/sP5ntTD2ta0" /> 
</video>
```

This makes styling the element, along with other div's that you place untop of it way easier.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: Jefferson, as i mentioned above, for some reasons i can't  touch main embed code. So i am not able to use HTML5 tag, it must be old youtube <object> embed code.

Have a look here(Chrome - OK, IE - nope): http://jsfiddle.net/b3w8S/

Comment: Have you tried downloading it and having the source direct to the downloaded file? This way you can convert it to multiple formats for different browsers.